# Shiny update table content based on pickerinput selection

Tags: shiny, output, dt, pickerinput

This is my first time using shiny. I built a database to feed an existing app. the new module I created (by modifying a by_country page one is too complex) and is not fully working.

The table "tablepreped.xlsx" is displaying and so are the drop-down menus but the filtering of the table is not updating when I change the selectors.

Basically, I want to select an indicator, and based on that have country names, gap sizes and  gap values filtered in my table and ideally be able to also select the gap size. If anybody could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it!

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go_to_aimm_landing, {

    hideElement("main_app")
    showElement("landing_page")

  })

  observeEvent(landing_page_return$page_selected_trigger(), {

    page_ <- landing_page_return$page_selected()

    updateNavbarPage(
      session,
      "nav_pages",
      selected = page_
    )

  landing_page_return <- callModule(
    landing_page_module,
    "landing_page_id"
  )

  by_country_return <- callModule(
    by_country_module,
    'by_country',
    indicator_dat = dat,
    rank_ranges = band_ranges,
    defaults = landing_page_return$default_selected
  )

  callModule(
    by_size_module,
    'by_size'
  )

  callModule(
    map_module,
    'map_id',
    default_selected = landing_page_return$default_selected
  )
}
```

server

```
by_size_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "Indicators",
      fluidRow(
        br(),
        column(
          width = 10,
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 12,
              tagList(
                fluidRow(
                  column(
                    width = 2,
                    pickerInput(
                      ns("country"),
                      "Country",
                      choices = choices$country,
                      selected = "Tanzania",
                      options = list(
                        'live-search' = TRUE,
                        'live-search-placeholder' = 'Search...',
                        'live-search-normalize' = TRUE,
                        'live-search-style' = 'contains'
                      ),
                      width = "100%"
                    )
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 4,
                    pickerInput(
                      ns("indicator_names"),
                      "Indicator",
                      choices = choices$indicator_names,
                      selected = "Adult account holders",
                      options = list(
                        'live-search' = TRUE,
                        'live-search-placeholder' = 'Search...',
                        'live-search-normalize' = TRUE,
                        'live-search-style' = 'contains'
                      ),
                      width = "100%"
                    )
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 2,
                    pickerInput(
                      ns("indicator_type"),
                      "Type of Indicator",
                      choices = choices$indicator_type,
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = c("gap", "intensity") %in% c("intensity")
                      ),
                      selected = "gap",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      options = pickerOptions(
                        actionsBox = TRUE,
                        liveSearch = TRUE,
                        liveSearchPlaceholder = 'Search...',
                        liveSearchNormalize = TRUE,
                        liveSearchStyle = 'contains'
                      ),
                      width = "100%"
                    )
                  ),
                  column(
                    width = 2,
                    pickerInput(
                      ns("gap_size"),
                      "Gap Size",
                      choices = choices$gap_size,
                      selected = "l",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      options = pickerOptions(
                        actionsBox = TRUE,
                        liveSearch = TRUE,
                        liveSearchPlaceholder = 'Search...',
                        liveSearchNormalize = TRUE,
                        liveSearchStyle = 'contains'
                      ),
                      width = "100%"
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            ),
            column(
              width = 12,
              h2(
                style = "margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 25px; white-space: nowrap;",
                "Indicator: ",
                textOutput(ns("sel_indicator_name"), inline = TRUE)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),

      tagList(DTOutput(ns("by_size_table")) %>%
          withSpinner(),
        tags$script(src = "by_country_time_series.js"),
        tags$script(paste0("by_country_module_js('", ns(''), "')"))
      ),
      br(),
      br()
    )
  )
}

by_size_module <- function(input, output, session, tablepreped, default_selected) {
  ns <- session$ns

  default_selected <- reactive({

    list(
      default_indicator_name = input$indicator_names,
      default_country = input$country,
      default_gap_size = input$gap_size,
      default_indicator_type = input$indicator_type
    )

  })


  ### GAP Ranges table ----------
  library('datasets')
  library("openxlsx")
  tablepreped <- read.xlsx("tablepreped.xlsx")

##Makes title reactive to indicator input
  indoc <- reactive({
    sel_indicator_name <- input$indicator_names

  })

  output$sel_indicator_name <- renderText({
    indoc()
  })


  # filter data for the selected indicator and gap size
  tablepreped_filtered <- reactive({
    gsize<-input$gap_size

    hold<-input$indicator_names

    hold_gap_size <- hold %>%
      dplyr::filter(gap_size == gsize)

    ctry_indicator_values <- hold_gap_size %>%
      select(country, gap_vals,gap_size)


  })

  # create data frame

    out <- tablepreped

    out<-out %>%
        select(
        country,
        indicator_name,
        gap_vals,
        gap_size
      )

  output$by_size_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(out,
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  class = "compact stripe",
                  options = list(orderClasses = TRUE)
                  )
  })
}
```

This is the data frame head

```
structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), code = c("gap_ind_0001", 
"gap_ind_0002", "gap_ind_0003", "gap_ind_0005", "gap_ind_0006", 
"gap_ind_0007"), indicator_name = c("Affordability ", 
"Infrastructure", "Poverty Rate", 
"Adjusted years of schooling", "Adult literacy", 
"Account holders, female"), s = c(70, 60, 67, 8, 58.2, 
55), m = c(60, 45, 50, 7, 39.5, 34.9), l = c(45, 30, 30, 5, 26, 
21.5), gap_size = c("vl", "l", "m", "vl", "s", "vl"), gap_vals = c(29.58082, 
23.3432, 18.330012, 4.87, 14.893313, 7.160684)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimal reproducible example? This means that you remove all code that is not necessary for the question, replace the reading in of the file with your example data and provide a working app, not just a module. Thanks!

Comment: Question, I have a global file and two other r.file for the UI and the server that also contain the navbar, they are pretty long, is that what I should share?

Comment: In principle yes, but try to provide only minimal ui/server/global functions, so remove everything from these files that is not relevant for your question, but still reproduces your error/question (I know it's easier said than done)

Comment: @starja, I made an update, I don't know if that's helpful. I worked in this this morning, I can see the table now but no connection between the selectors and the filtering of the table. I have a question : does it make a difference to have the "ui" and the "server" input in the same file?

Comment: You can put `server` and `ui` into the same file, no problem. However, your edited example is not a minimal example: 1. the ui is missing, 2. no packages are loaded, 3. in the server you have a lot of code that is not relevant and won't run (the other modules), 4. your module loads a dataset that is not provided

Comment: You use `out` as the dataset to display the table, but `out` itself is not a reactive so you can't filter it for your inputs

Comment: and you have `tablepreped` both as an argument to your module and define it inside your module, which is not good style (as you don't use the argument)

Comment: @starja thanks for taking the time to look at it. I'm going to continue to work on it and edit the content of my question so it's not as messy and confusing. re : out, I think that's where the main issue is